# Will Win7 ImageCreate overwrite the MBR?

Tags: windows-7, installation, images, mbr

Using Win7 64bit.

If i use the Win7 Image Create in the backup/restore app, when i go to re-install the image will it competely overwrite everything, including the MBR???

I want to be able to do total clean backups, cause i believe i got hit wiht a virus and not having success removing it. After i fix this, get everything clean, in case this ever occurs again. Just want to be able to take out the image and wipe out the problem.

Unless someone can help me with the Startupnow toolbar and MySearchresults virus.
None of the scans are detecting it, but my chrome browser will not lose the home page redirecting its doing. Even after removing the extension/add-on and settgn the homepage back to google. The browser still will come up with MySearchResults.com.

Tried all kinds of stuff online, MBrCheck(my usb external drive had issue, ntohing on boot drive) and TDDSSKiller(found nothing).

I'm thinking clean install and wipe MBR. Then once i get all the apps reinstalled, to take an image. Hoping this will also take a MBR image.

Does Win7 image create wipe the MBR also?
On a side note.
What virus/internet protection does everyone recommend?
How do i handle my external and other data files internal(F:\ drive)? Are they corrupt as well?

Comment: Just wipe the MBR yourself. If you create a backup image as is, what you restore, will still be infected with those semi-malicious files.  You should be able to remove both by using www.malwarebytes.org/

Comment: Plan on wiping the boot drive + MBR, starting over, then taking an image of that clean drive. So, next time i am prepared. But just was wondering if the MBR was wiped wiht an image install?